# LookUp issue in Union query MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, lookup-tables

I have two queries which are having fields Role and Description. I've created a `Union` query out of these two queries.

Query 1 is from table `Building1` and second query from table `Building2`

But field `Role` is a combo filled by `LookUp` query from Base table `Role` and used `Bound Column` to display `name`

When I execute the queries, I am getting the results correctly whereas when I run the `union`, field `Role` giving me the `RoleId` instead of name

Could someone tell/explain why it behaves and what's the work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the table Role twice to the query.

Then join their Ids to the RoleId og Building1 and Building2 respectively.